# What is the computational complexity of expression minimization over a distributive lattice?

Tags: order-theory, computational-complexity, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

If we start with Boolean algebra and eliminate the negation operation, making it [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws), we get a free distributive lattice ('$\mathrm{M}$' in [Post's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice)).

I'm curious about the effect on questions of complexity.  CNF-SAT becomes trivial, so what about something more interesting, the Minimum Equivalent Expression problem?  While the [decision problem version for ordinary Boolean formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization#Circuit_minimization_in_Boolean_algebra) is $\Sigma_2^\mathrm{P}$-complete, I think that corollary 2.8 from (1) shows MEE to be $\Pi^\mathrm{P}_1$-hard in the monotone case; is that correct?  And is that the most accurate bound we have?

---

(1) Edith Hemaspaandra and Henning Schnoor. 2011. [Minimization for generalized Boolean formulas](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2312). In Proceedings of the Twenty-Second international joint conference on Artificial Intelligence - Volume Volume One (IJCAI'11). AAAI Press, 566–571.